# What to do with a lot dried habaneros?

Tags: chili-peppers

I have grown a lot of habanero chillis last year in my garden. It turns out that they are too hot for most meals I cook. Not knowing what to do with them, I dried them.

Since then, I still do not know what to cook. Do you have any ideas what to cook with the dried habaneros? I don't want to throw them away...

(I usually like chillies, and the heat)

Thank you!

Comment: My mom dries and crushes them, so she can just sprinkle in what she needs into dishes without using them whole.  Just be careful if you use a food processor, as you'll end up pepper spraying yourself when you take the lid off.

Comment: Are they still too hot without the seeds/membranes?

Answer (score 4):

As they're too hot, your options are reduced to dilution or donation. By the latter I simply mean giving them to a friendly chilli head who doesn't grow their own.

To dilute dried chillies, first crush them or put them through a food processor to get flakes. Then use the flakes sparingly. If you add them to oil just after frying onions etc. for a dish, the oil will absorb some of the heat and distribute it throughout the dish. This works in a wide range of dishes (pasta sauces, stir fries, chilli, curry...). Of course they'll last a long time this way, but that's OK. Store them in a glass jar with a tight lid and they'll keep for years with only a little loss of flavour.